# How to create json file from mysql ( Big data )?

Tags: php, mysql

Previously, I had successfully created a json file with 25000 data. But if data is 100000, create json file error.

my query :

```
$results = $db->SELECT()
                ->FROM( array(  'MM'=>'M_MEMBER'),
                        array(  'MEMBER_ID'      => 'MM.MEMBER_ID',
                                'FIRST_NAME'     => 'MM.FIRST_NAME',
                                'LAST_NAME'      => 'MM.LAST_NAME',
                                'MEMBER_GROUP'   => 'MM.MEMBER_GROUP',
                                'MEMBER_GROUP1'  => 'MM.MEMBER_GROUP1',
                                'PHONE_NUMBER'   => 'MM.PHONE_NUMBER',
                                'MEMBERSHIP'     => 'MM.MEMBERSHIP',
                                'UPLOAD_DATE'    => 'MM.UPLOAD_DATE',
                                'STATUS'         => 'MM.STATUS'
                             )
                      )
                ->WHERE('DATE(MM.UPLOAD_DATE) = CURDATE()')
                ->QUERY()->FETCHALL();
```

How to partially generate json file if 100000 data becomes 4 json files, with each file 25000 data.
No duplicate data

Comment: What is the reason to retrieve data to PHP and then save it whereas MySQL can both build needed JSON and save it to disk file? `SELECT JSON_OBJECT(..) .. INTO OUTFILE ..`

Comment: When you dealing with big amount of data `FETCHALL()` is not an option. It will try to fetch all data and if the size of requested data will be bigger then `php_memory_limit` then you will get an error and json file wont be generated or generated partialy depending on your logic. You don't need to split the file, you need to fetch data in batches/chunks and write it on the fly to the json file in background process instead of using web server thread for example.